# reading writing google drive spreadsheets using java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am working on creating a web application using java through which I can access my google drive spreadsheet and copy its contents into other sheet. the problem I am facing is:

whether google.gdata or google-api-java-client is to be used for reading and writing in google drive spreadsheet?I am really confused about the steps to do so.I have obtained authorization code and token as well but then again was struck  what to do next?

Comment: I have found 'gdata api' is deprecated but then how to use spreadsheets api??

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation for this here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/